# Counting rows from second table

Tags: php, mysql, count, left-join

I have two tables in mysql database

groups

```
id|name
_______
1 |red
2 |blue
3 |green
4 |white
```

and users

```
id|name  |group
_______________
1 |joe   |1
2 |max   |1
3 |anna  |2
4 |lisa  |2
```

So... joe and max are in the "red" group, anna and lisa are in the "blue" group.

How can I make simple listing of groups which would contain the number of
persons in that group
For example

```
red - 2
blue - 2
green - 0
white - 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select g.name, count(u.id) from groups g
left join users u on g.id = u.group
group by g.id, g.name
```

Answer (score 1):

check if this works....

```
SELECT COUNT(*), groups.name FROM groups, users WHERE users.group=groups.id GROUP BY groups.name
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT groups.name, COUNT(users.*) FROM groups LEFT JOIN users
ON groups.id=users.group GROUP BY groups.name
```

this will keep the colors even if they dont have any name related

Answer (score 1):

Most the other answers are basically correct, but forgot an important detail: `GROUP` is a reserved word in SQL, so your column name must be escaped:

```
SELECT groups.name, COUNT(*) AS total_members
FROM groups 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
ON users.`group` = groups.id
GROUP BY groups.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(g.id) as count, g.name 
FROM groups as g
LEFT JOIN users as u 
ON u.group = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT g.*, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) FROM `groups` g
INNER JOIN `users` u on g.id = u.group
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should work

```
SELECT g.name, COUNT( u.id ) AS Totoal
FROM  `groups` g
INNER JOIN  `users` u ON g.id = u.group
GROUP BY g.id
```